# Finding a basis of annihilator.

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

Consider $\mathbb{P}_2$ as a subspace of $\mathbb{P}_3$. Compute a basis for the annihilator of $\mathbb{P}_2$.

We know dim$\mathbb{P}_3$=4, and dim$\mathbb{P}_2$=3, so dim$(\mathbb{P}_2)^0$=1.

So, some $\varphi \in (\mathbb{P}_2)^0$ is a basis of $(\mathbb{P}_2)^0$.

Then, we can say $\varphi$ is defined by $\varphi(f)=f^{(3)}$ where $f^{(3)}$ is a notation for $f$'s $3$-rd derivative.

Is it the right answer with proper reasoning?

This doesn't seem enough to me because the answer doesn't even consider the dim$\mathbb{P}_3$=4. $\mathbb{P}_2$ can either be a subset of $\mathbb{P}_4$ as well. Then dim$(\mathbb{P}_2)^0$=2. But, in that case what should be considered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks fine. You could also instead take $\phi(c_3 x^3 + c_2 x^2 + c_1 x + c_0) := c_3$. Your $\varphi$ is $6\phi$.

If the vector space is $\mathbb{P}_4$ instead, then you have an additional functional $\tilde{\phi}(c_4 x^4 + c_3 x^3 + \cdots + c_0) := c_4$ (or the fourth derivative).

Comment: Why does it have to be $6 \phi$?

Comment: @john I'm just saying that $\frac{d^3}{dx^3}(c_3 x^3 + c_2 x^2 + c_1 x + c_0) = 6 c_3$ as a sanity check that both our solutions are in the same one-dimensional subspace.